# Applying a text colour to an individual ActionBar menu item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'd like to have one of the `MenuItem`s in my app's action bar change colour based on its value. There are other items which should retain the default style so I can't apply styles to the whole action bar, it's got to just be to this one item. I've tried using a `SpannableString` like so:

```
MenuItem item = getActionBar().findItem(R.id.item_id);
SpannableString colouredString = new SpannableString("Item");

colouredString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
    booleanStatement ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN
), 0, colouredString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

item.setTitle(colouredString);
```

This sets the value correctly, but the item's text colour is unaffected. If I add in

```
getActionBar().setTitle(colouredString);
```

then the title is set as expected, with the text colour applied. Is there a way of making `SpannableString` work on `MenuItem`s as well as the overall action bar title? Or an alternative way of setting the text colour of an action bar menu item?

Comment: Have You tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598015/different-look-style-for-specific-menu-item-on-actionbar ?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted...somehow didn't come up in my searches. Thank you!